# WordPress register multiple blocks returns error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to register multiple custom blocks using the method in this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407748/how-to-register-two-blocks-in-the-same-plugin

I have created two folders within the SRC folder and am registering the blocks like so :

```
function register_custom_blocks() {
    register_block_type( THEME_PATH . '/blocks/image-link/build/image-link' );
    register_block_type( THEME_PATH . '/blocks/image-link/build/video-popup' );
};
add_action('init', 'register_custom_blocks');
```

I have also tried pointing to the `/src` directory.

Here is the folder structure :

[image]

But WordPress throw the following error:

```
Function register_block_script_handle was called incorrectly.
The asset file (/home/virtus3projekti/md-konstrukcije.virtus3-projekti.com/wp-content/themes/vd-md-konstrukcije/blocks/image-link/build/image-link/build/image-link/index.asset.php) 
for the "editorScript" defined in "fa-gutenberg-blocks/image-link" 
block definition is missing. Please see
```

Comment: Hi. Stack Overflow [discourages use of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) for code/error/debug/log messages. Images create problems for usability, readability, and searchability among many other problems. Please post the content of your code and error messages into your question as text.

Comment: @kofeigen replaced with text